# A program to check weather a bank account is having Sufficient balance or Not in javascript

Tags: javascript, comparison

i have a small silly doubt, as explained in Question..
i prepared this code..
it's not recognizing the bank account Number and keep on saying..NOT An ACCOUNT NUMBER.!!
any help...and having trouble with comparing strings and numbers in other programs of mine..
By the way **i started learning J-script 4 days ago**, So Please be simple. :)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> New Document </title>
        <meta name="Author" content="">
<!-- writw a program to check weather the bank account have a sufficient ballence or not -->
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
            function bankValidation()
            {
                var acc=document.myBank.accNum;
                var acc_len=acc.value.length;

                if(acc_len == 0)
                    alert("Account Number Field Is Empty!");
                if(acc === 123456)
                    alert("Your Balance is 1000000");
                else
                    alert("Not an account Number!");
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="myBank" onSubmit="bankValidation()" method="post">
            <table class=table1 bgcolor=lightgrey>
                <tr>
                    <td width=150>Bank Account No:</td>
                    <td><input name="accNum" type="text" id="accNum" value="12345" width="100"></input></td>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan=2 align=middle></input>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="check"></td>

            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: it's really simple you have one typo in    if(acc === 123456)  "==" you should use "==" and it will work

Comment: no i tried that too but,@dystroy helped me out.. Thanks...

Comment: I tested yours and it really worked for me. welcome.

Comment: can u help me out with converting from one type to other in javascript...Like sending some links..which are really help me...

Comment: which type to which type do you mean? please be more specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you want is

1. to get the value of the field
2. to parse it as a number

Replace

```
var acc=document.myBank.accNum;
var acc_len=acc.value.length;
```

with

```
var acc= parseFloat(document.myBank.accNum.value);
var acc_len=document.myBank.accNum.value.length;
```

Comment: OMG That was QUICK Thanks... but can u redirect me to some materials or articles about this topics :)

Comment: I'm not sure. You might pick the pages that looks helpful to you after having searched "input html", or "input mdn".

Comment: does MDN stands for MOZILLA DEVELOPER NETWORK!..i got redirected to here...**Thanks**... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input

Comment: Yes, and the MDN generally is the most reliable source of information for everything web related.